# -Java ¿ Se puede parametrizar una columna con preparedStatement?

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statements

Tengo un dropdown que cuando el usuario la selecciona consulta una columna de una db.
El problema es que me pueden hacer SQLinyection con las options del mismo.
Al lado del dropdown tengo un campo que ese también consulta a la db pero está parametrizado, quería saber si también podía parametrizar la columna.

pd: leí por muchos lados que no, pero un compañero en su código me mostró que si valía y quería saber que dicen ustedes, gracias.

Comment: No es posible Enzo. [Aquí te dejo una fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3136049/5587982), ya que no me creíste en mis comentarios a tu anterior pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: De hecho como alguien comento en ese link que te pusieron: `El uso de nombres de columna dentro de las listas de valores de  preparedStatement es, por supuesto posible, pero eso no significa que deba usarse de esa manera, todavía es un mal diseño`. Debido a que es un mal diseño no creo que alguien te responda aunque sepamos como hacerlo.